# C# neomake linter

Tags: vimrc, neovim, plugin-neocomplete

I would like to use nvim more for C# however I am having a maker error I can't fix.
My Omnisharp didn't work either but I still have 'YCM' as a backup for now.

The MSBuild in my path is from the VS tools directory, I am able to compile straight from the commandline.
However when opening a C sharp file when I enter :NeomakeInfo  the debug message starts with the following error

```
Neomake: Maker not found (for filetype cs): MSBuild.
```

I specified the maker in my init.vim like this:

```
let b:neomake_cs_enabled_makers = ['MSBuild']
```

I am able to use 'pylint' by specifying it like this so why not this for c#

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You may have more luck troubleshooting with the neomake authors

Comment: Thanks, yeah on second thought I figured this might not be the best place. Will look for a appropriate place to ask this on github.

Comment: Have you defined your maker as described in [:h neomake-makers-exe](https://github.com/neomake/neomake/blob/master/doc/neomake.txt#L242) from the docs?

Comment: No I haven't seen these docs, I mostly read the logs, info command and github readme. I had no idea this was a thing. Will look into how to define this for c sharp, thanks. Currently I have just 'let g:neomake_cs_enabled_makers=['MSBuild']'

Comment: Well the function fixed the neomake not finding the maker. Only need to findout how to make it display in editor like the pylint does. It's probably in the docs somewhere. Thanks @Jake Grossman